# How many two-dimensional space filling Hilbert-like curves are there?

Tags: gn.general-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, fractals

I'm interested in filling 2d square with space filling, non-self-intersecting, locality preserving, self-similar curves,  like Hilbert curve. I found interesting work concerning three dimensional case "How many three-dimensional Hilbert curves are there?" http://www4.ncsu.edu/~njrose/pdfFiles/HilbertCurve.pdf  but I need 2d.

Actually I'm looking for plane filling non-self-intersecting curves with short Lindenmayer representation. But I have no ideas how to generate all those except with brute-force. Is there any literature on the subject?

Comment: What do you mean by a "plane filling non-self-intersecting curve"? The paper to which you gave a link does not include this notion.

Comment: I’m pretty sure plane filling curves can’t be bijective.

Comment: @ThomasRot I meant like Hilbert curve it can self-contact without self-crossing.

Comment: @WlodekKuperberg I would like curves which behave like Hilbert curve. Its limit fills the square while finite representation it is not self-intersecting and even limit case is self-contacting without self-crossing.

Comment: You probably need a definition of "self crossing".

Comment: In this paper (https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864106002720/1-s2.0-S0166864106002720-main.pdf?_tid=7ef0f73a-279c-43f1-bbb5-f09a7b0f26bc&acdnat=1538855108_7af575c3f91a34af65619c3ee9682c40) we construct some Peano curves with control on their Holder constants. Maybe this will be helpful?

Comment: Maybe you should also clarify what the Lindenmeyer representation is.